# How to setup <Directory> and ProxyPass simultaneously on Apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have a running rails application running under `myapp.site.com`. This app is running inside on port `9000` and we're using apache's `ProxyPass`.

All the pages are currently being served by rails, but now I've got a JS app I want to serve on `/account` route and subroutes. This app's files are under `/var/www/my-vue-app/dist`.

How can I setup this using apache? I've tried setting up two `<VirtualHost>`; making an exception for everything that's not `/account`, and a bunch of other hacky solutions to no luck

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Found how to configure apache, basically I just needed to exclude the specific route on ProxyPass and apache serves the  as expected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/dist

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /account !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/

    Alias /account /var/www/myapp/dist
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/dist>
            DirectoryIndex index.html
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /account
            RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /account/index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```